# FileオブジェクトのlastModifiedDateプロパティの有無

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="file" id="filePicker">

<script>
document.getElementById('filePicker')
    .addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.files[0].lastModified);
        console.log(e.target.files[0].lastModifiedDate);
    }, false);
</script>
```

上記を４種類のブラウザで動かして、lastModifiedとlastModifiedDateのそれぞれが存在するかどうかを確認しました。

(A) IE11
lastModifiedDate のみ有り

(B) ChromeおよびFireFox
lastModifiedとlastModifiedDateのどちらも有り

(C) Safari10
lastModified のみ有り

質問です。

(1) [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#file)にはlastModifiedDateについて記述されていません。lastModifiedDateは非標準なプロパティなのでしょうか。

(2) 上記(B)ではlastModifiedとlastModifiedDateに同じ日付が設定されていることを手元で動かして確認しましたが、なにか違いはあるのでしょうか（日付の形式以外に）。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[2013年9月のW3C草案](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-FileAPI-20130912/#file-attrs)では `lastModifiedDate` だったのが、[2015年4月の草案](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-FileAPI-20150421/#file-attrs)では `lastModified` になっているので、その間に変更されたようですね。Firefoxでも廃止予定だそうです。

参考 [File.lastModifiedDate が廃止予定となりました | Firefox サイト互換性情報](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/ja/docs/2016/file-lastmodifieddate-has-been-deprecated/)

これらの文章を読む限りでは、Date型から数値に変わっただけで、それが指す時間は同じかと。